# How to create a function inside a class that replaces itself with a copy of another object?

Tags: python, class

I want to create a function inside a class that replaces itself with a copy of another object of that class. A very rudimentary example is given below, but this seems too manual and imagine it might have other problems like not copying over new methods.

Is there a pythonic way of doing this?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b

    def Replaceme(self,NewCls):
        self.a=NewCls.a
        self.b=NewCls.b
```

Comment: don't give functions such names `Replaceme`

Comment: See [**_Function Names_**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) in the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (although you _may_ get a pass this time since the name is `Replaceme` `;-)`—except `NewCls` is also not the recommended letter-casing to use for variable names)